# Backbone Model is a function?

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs

I have the following function, which fails when called:

```
getAll: function() {
    return _todos.toJSON();
}
```

`_todos.toJSON is not a function` it tells me.

Printing `_todos` gives me a function for some reason `function child()`.
Why is that the case?

Here's my `Backbone.Model`:

```
var _todos = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

The `getAll()` function is sitting in my `Collection`:

```
var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: _todos,
    getAll: ...
});
```

**Edit:**
I'm actually connecting Backbone with React, so that might change how I do this.

In addition to `getAll` I have this:

```
areAllComplete: function() {
    return _.every(this.pluck('complete'), true);
 }
```

An [example](https://github.com/shaohua/todomvc-react-flux-backbone/blob/master/js/stores/TodoStore.js) I've been following seems to put `getAll` and `areAllComplete` in the `Model` and doesn't use `Collection` at all. I couldn't make sense of it, and since I want this to be restful down the road, I added the `Collection` and moved `getAll` and other one inside of it.

Perhaps, this is not what I want.

**Edit 2:**
According to a warning, the output of `getAll` is expected to be an `Object` not an `array`. I should probably add those function to `Model` not `Collection`. Need to think about this more.

I think this turned into another question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection [model](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) property is used to specify what model class the collection contains and is used to create the proper models when you pass the raw data to your collection. Additionally based on your code if it did work you would have had a collection with just one model.

Aside from that in order to get the *JSON* of all the models in your collection you can call it's [toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) method

for example `todoCollection.toJSON();`

Or if you specifically want it in a getAll function (maybe you want to do something else before returning the data) you can do the following

```
var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,
    getAll: function () {
      //do something
      return this.toJSON();
    }
});

//here we are passing in the data directly, but you might get it with a fetch call
var todoStore = new TodoCollection(models); 
var todosJson = todoStore.getAll();
```

Another thing to note is the backbone naming [convention](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#conventions) is to use PascalCase for *classes* and camelCase for instances .

Comment: I see. If want to keep my `getAll()` in my `Collection`, since it hasn't been defined yet, how do I make the call. `this.` doesn't work because of scoping. Or do you recommend sticking that function outside? I want to be able to call `TodoStore.getAll()` where `TodoStore` is an instance of the `Collection`.

Comment: You can still include your `getAll()` function in your collection, it will be defined on your TodoCollection prototype. To use it you would create an instance of your collection something like `var TodoStore = new TodoCollection();` and then `ToDoStore.getAll();`

Comment: where my `getAll()` returns `TodoCollection.toJSON()`? I'm getting `TodoCollection.toJSON is not a function`

Comment: @Pushkin I've updated my answer, hopefully that clarifies it a bit more (unless I'm misunderstanding what your trying to do).

Comment: haha perhaps I don't understand what I'm trying to do. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Backbone.Model.extend` returns a constructor function. When you pass it to a collection via the `model` property you're just letting the collection know which kind of models it should hold.

To get the JSON for an entire collection, call `toJSON()` on the collection instance.

```
var collection = new TodosCollection();
// add models
collection.toJSON();
```

If you want JSON for one specific model then get a reference to it via the collection API (`at`, `findWhere`, `get` etc) and call `toJSON()` on that reference.

```
var model = collection.at(0);
model.toJSON();
```